# Where is the scoped Prism RegionManager for my tab control?

Tags: wpf, prism, mef, prism-5

Using `Prism 5.0`. My shell is instantiated from a `MefBootstrapper` derived class. The shell has a `MainRegion` where views are added using the `AutoPopulateExportedViewsBehavior` (found in the *StockTraderRI* sample). **This works perfectly.**

However, in one of my views that is loaded into the `MainRegion`, there is a `TabControl` where I want to add active-aware viewmodels in runtime. The `IActiveAware` interface only works if the control is inside a region, and a region does not allow me to bind to `ItemsSource`. Hence this construct:

```
<TabControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="TabRegion">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyTabViewModel1}">
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyTabViewModel2}">
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

So I thought that I could add the viewmodels in runtime, when my main viewmodel is activated (via `IActiveAware`):

```
protected override void OnActiveChanged(bool active)
{
    if (active)
    {
        // This code crashes.
        // The region does not exist in the root region manager...
        var region = regionManager.Regions["TabRegion"];
    }
}
```

The problem is that this code crashes. I guess this means that I have a reference to the root region manager. How do I get hold of the scoped region manager?

Comment: How do you get hold of the regionManager in the code sample? did it come from Mef through the constructor?

Comment: Yes! From MEF, using the importing constructor. I noticed that the region can be found later on (after tab control loaded?), so I'm starting to suspect that IActiveAware.IsActive is set before the region name is set/created. Not sure how to address that issue.